# C++ WinApi Tab Help Calling Main Static Bar

Tags: c++, winapi, tabs, controls

Hello all I hope someone can help me I am working on a simple application which uses tab controls I have set this up and working fine. My handlers for the second dialog tab is below and contains a pop up to confirm the button was clicked which works ok.

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK TabDialogTwo(HWND hwndDlg,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) 
{ 
    switch (uMsg) 
    { 
   case WM_INITDIALOG: 
        break; 
        case WM_COMMAND:      
            { 

            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) 
            { 
            case IDC_CHECK_ACCOUNT: 
                // This doesnt work
                   HWND hwndStatic = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_STATIC1);
   Static_SetText(hwndStatic, "Button Works");
   // This does as expected 
                MessageBox(hwndDlg,TEXT("User Account Selected"),TEXT("Button"),0); 
                break; 
            } 
            break; 
            } 

    } 
    return FALSE ; 
}
```

My problem is the buttons which are on my tab controls wont update my static bar using this code

```
// This doesnt work from inside the tab window but does work in my intial dialog function
      HWND hwndStatic = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_STATIC1);
      Static_SetText(hwndStatic, "Button Works???");
```

Do I need to change the handle to hwnd->hwndDlg ? this comes up undefined as its not.

All I want to do is be able to change my status bar from within the tab controls is this possible?  I have searched for 8 days now non stop so thought I would ask the experts.

Many thanks

UPDATE FIXED : See Pezcode Example below. thanks to all helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
HWND hwndStatic = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_STATIC1);
```

with

```
HWND hwndStatic = GetDlgItem(GetParent(GetParent(hwndDlg)), IDC_STATIC1);
```

`GetDlgItem` only gets controls inside the window you give to it. `hwndDlg` in that context is the dialog inside the tab. But to get the `hwndStatic` handle to the static bar of the main dialog, you have to get up two levels (via the `GetParent` API).
Once up is the tab control, another one up is your main dialog.

Comment: thanks Pezcode it worked. You made me so happy was about to bin the whole thing. Also Luskan and Gunner thx top guys.